# Write the log in to existing common log file using slf4j

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I have multiple services and each one of them interacting with each other. There is `common.log` file where I am writing the common log in to this file. logback.xml entry for this `common.log` is present in to another service lets name it as Service1. I want to write the some common things in to this existing `common.log` file using slf4j.

I tried to write a utility class to write the log from Service2 application to `common.log` and using the `java.util.logging` package as below ,

```
public class LogUtil {

    private static LogUtil instance = new LogUtil();

    public static LogUtil getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogUtil.class.getName());

    static {
        try {
            String logFile = System.getProperty("home") + "/logs/common.log";
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(logFile, true);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);
            logger.addHandler(fh);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void error(String msg) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"[Error Common] :"+msg);
    }
}
```

I want to do it using the slf4j api. Please suggest me some approach to write the utility class using slf4j.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Why aren't you defining the handler and formatter via a configuration file, e.g. in logback.xml? You could do it just for a specific logger if you need to. 2) Your class would always use the `LogUtil` logger, i.e. you wouldn't know where the error would originate especially since you don't log the stack trace as well. Is that really what you want? 3) Do you really need `instance` given that all the code could be static (`error()` doesn't access any instance method/field so could be static as well)?

Comment: This is going to used for some common error and method error)) which receive the error details as method param. This common.log is existing and its already having the logback entry and configuration in respective module/service. I just want to append the error from some other service/module in existing common.log

Comment: Still, why don't you use logback configuration in that other service or modukle? What that separate class to do the configuration? You also didn't provide any reason why `error()` could not be static.

Comment: its already in other service